# libreOffice - cannot get python macros to appear under 'Organize Macros'

Tags: python, libreoffice, calc, libreoffice-basic

I am working with LibreOffice V6.4, running under Mint 20.  I have read ad nauseum about setting up python macros with **Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros** but cannot get anything I add to appear there.  At the end of that click chain the only thing that appears is **Basic**.

I have set up the following directory structure which is what the online help says should work:

```
$HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user/
                               |
                               |--Basic/              (this stuff is visible in dialog)
                               |      |
                               |      |--Standard/
                               |                |
                               |                |--Module1.xba   (contains my basic macros)
                               |
                               |
                               |--python/                  (none of this is visible)
                               |      |
                               |      |--Standard/
                               |      |         |
                               |      |         |--test2.py
                               |      |
                               |      |--test1.py
```

Nothing I do makes **python** show up in the menu tree (it should appear under **Basic**) so I can get to the dialog box that lets me work with a python module.  As you can see I tried putting python files at different levels of the tree - but **python" simply doesn't appear in the LibreOffice Calc menu and dialog actions.

What am I doing wrong here?  Is there some step that must be made with a configuration dialog or something to enable this stuff?  I have not been able to find any reference related to that.  BTW I have macro security set to medium but I don't think that's an issue here (I can run all my basic macros).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python` for simple scripts - `$HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user/uno_packages/cache/uno_packages/` for packages

Comment: Are you aware of [this extension](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/en/extensions/show/apso-alternative-script-organizer-for-python)?

Comment: In response to first suggestion above, I actually do have a python file in 
$HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user/Scripts/python - but it does not appear anywhere in the libreoffice menus or dialogs.  I am going to take a look at apso though (second suggestion).

Comment: The text in your question suggests that you don't. It says you have it in `$HOME/.config/libreoffice/4/user/python` missing a vital `Scripts` directory.